# Variable not changing on if statement

Tags: javascript

I am working on code for a site am trying to take an input and based on the input display a specific message. Whenever I type in a number however it is being set to the first if result. Any help would be great, thanks

```
    <form name="testsDone">
   How many of your tests have you taken? <input type ="text" id="tookTests" /><br />
</form>


<script>
function testCheck(){ 
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tookTests").value);
  var b = a;
  var c;

  if (b = 2 ) {
    c = "Yes you can! You've earned it.";
    } else if (b = 1) {
    c = "You need to keep studying then";
    } 
    else if (b > 2 ) {
    c = "That's more tests than you're supposed to have";
    }else {
    c = "Why are you on here? You need to study.";
}

 document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = c;
}
   </script>
   <button onclick="testCheck()">Check and See</button>
   <p> Can you go to sleep?</p>
   <p id="change"></p>
```

Comment: Equality is `==` or `===`, not `=`

Comment: = is assignment, == is comparison http://jshint.com/

Comment: `==` for comparison, `=` for assignment

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value here..

if (b = 2 ) {

it should be..

if (b == 2 ) {

Answer (score -1):

Hey change it to the following

```
function testCheck(){ 
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tookTests").value);
  var b = a;
  var c;

  if (b == 2 ) {
    c = "Yes you can! You've earned it.";
    } else if (b == 1) {
    c = "You need to keep studying then";
    } 
    else if (b > 2 ) {
    c = "That's more tests than you're supposed to have";
    }else {
    c = "Why are you on here? You need to study.";
}

 document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = c;
}
```